Which is recommended to learn first: classic themes or block themes?
Which is recommended to learn first: classic themes or block themes? I'm a beginner who recently started learning WordPress theme development.
For someone who’s developing with WordPress for the first time, should I start by learning classic theme development? (Are there many concepts that overlap between both types of theme development?) I've heard that migrating a site from a classic theme to a block theme can be challenging, so I'm unsure which one to focus on.

I'd suggest starting with classic themes, especially the Loop and the template hierarchy. That'll give you a solid foundation of how WP has worked for most of its history. Once you've done that, you can bolt block themes on top of your existing sound base of knowledge the same way they were bolted on top of WP.
